# How to update an URL on toggling a drop down in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to update an URL based on value of a dropdown. Through what function can I update the URL.

```
 handleChange = (e) => {
      // update client code
      this.setState({ clientcode: e.target.value.substr(0, 5),
        value: e.target.value,
      });
      // now update url
      // this.props.history.push('/v4/adminv2/web.php/client-onboard/family-management/api/packet?clientcode=' + this.state.clientcode);
      const state = "";
      const title = "";
      const url = '/v4/adminv2/web.php/client-onboard/family-management/api/packet?clientcode=' + this.state.clientcode;
      window.history.pushState(state, title, url);
    }
```

For every change in dropdown, the this.state.clientcode in the URL needs to be updated and reload the page.

Couldn't see any change in the url after change in dropdown value.

Comment: Are these routes being handled by React Router or are you expecting a new http request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation for [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState). It takes three arguments

> `history.pushState(state, title, url);`

Maybe try

```
window.history.pushState(undefined, undefined, `your/url/${e.target.value}`)
```

Although I disagree with the usage of `pushState` here. Why just not use `` this.props.history.push(`your/url/${e.target.value}`) ``?

**EDIT - New answer added to reflect changed question**

Answer (score 2):

you can use the history object  passed from the router:

```js
handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({ 
    clientcode: e.target.value.substr(0, 5),
    value: e.target.value,
  });
  const url = `/v4/adminv2/web.php/client-onboard/family-management/api/packet?clientcode=${this.state.clientcode}`
  props.history.push(url);
}
```

and this will not reload the page

Answer (score 2):

You said you want to reload the page, so I think that using window.history.pushState won't fit for your use case. Also looks like you're using a query string on the URL `?clientcode=${this.state.clientcode}`. I guess the best solution for doing exactly what you want (change the URL and reload) is to use window.location.href, it would look something like this:

```
window.location.href += `?${this.state.clientcode}`;
```

For a simple case where you are just changing the current URL with the new query parameters this would work perfectly. However if you need to go to a completely different URL you will end up using:

```
window.location.href += `${window.location.host}/your-url-path-here?${this.state.clientcode}`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Going with my gut, I believe the reason you aren't seeing the state update immediately is because you are using `this.state` and `this.setState` imperatively. React is declarative. The state won't be available until the next render cycle.

You might have better luck directly using `e.target.value`

```
const url = '/v4/adminv2/web.php/client-onboard/family-management/api/packet?clientcode=' + e.target.value.substr(0, 5)
```

Overall, you could simplify your code:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  const clientcode = e.target.value.substr(0, 5);
  const value = e.target.value;
  // update client code
  this.setState({ clientcode, value });
  const url = `/v4/adminv2/web.php/client-onboard/family-management/api/packet?clientcode=${clientcode}`;
  window.history.pushState('', '', url);
}
```

Comment: Just a note, this.setState returns a Promise, so you can either put your code in a .then or await for the state update to finish. You don't necessarily need to wait the next render cycle to finish before you get the updated state.

Comment: @WendelNascimento thanks for that, this info will change my life! (Although, I prefer you use functional components + useState)